# Calculating AVG; output those higher than the average

Tags: postgresql

Find all live albums that were released by artists from
CA (Canada) and that have a higher rating than the average rating of all albums (of any type, by any artist) released in the same year. For each album satisfying the requirements, output its title, artist’s name, and year (in this order).

Comment: Your query is where? This really looks like homework, so you really ought to demonstrate an attempt at this solution. Using a cte should be OK for this.

Answer (score 1):

use window function to do this:

```
select t.album, t.name artist, t.year 
  from (
    select b.name album, a.name, b.year, b.ratings, avg(b.ratings) over (partition by b.year) year_rat
      from albums b, artists a, countries c
     where a.country=c.code
       and c.code='CA1'
       and a.name=b.artist
 ) t
 where t.ratings >= t.year_rat
```

Or, if using no window functions:

```
select albums.title, artists.name, albums.year
  from artists 
  join albums on albums.artist= artists.name
  join (select year, avg(ratings) avg_ratings from albums group by year) As temp 
    on temp.year=albums.year
 where artists.country='CA1'
   and albums.ratings >= temp.avg_ratings
```

Comment: I added what I have so far to the main post. What's a way to do this without using over/partition by? Thanks, I appreciate the response!